# C# partial class returns null

Tags: c#, null, infopath, partial-classes

I'm trying to create populate an infopath template and upload it to sharepoint. I've been following these instructions https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33228/Programmatically-create-a-browser-enabled-InfoPath

Here is a sample of the generated code that I have

public partial class myFields:

```
...
public partial class myFields
{ 
    private General_Information general_InformationField;
    ...
    public General_Information General_Information
    {
        get
        {
            return this.general_InformationField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.general_InformationField = value;
        }
    }
    ...
}
...
```

public partial class General_Information

```
public partial class General_Information
{

    private string wellField;
    ...

    public string Well
    {
        get
        {
            return this.wellField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.wellField = value;
        }
    }
    ...
```

The instructions populate the data this:

```
myFields fields = new myFields();
fields.Name = "Joe";
fields.Surname = "Blogs";
```

When I tried to follow the example in the website:

```
myFields fields = new myFields();
fields.General_Information.Well = "name";
```

I get an error saying **myFields.General_Information.**get** returned null.**

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: `General_Information` is null.  You need to initialize it with an instance.

Comment: Partial classes are not relevant to this issue.  A partial class is a single class that exists across multiple files.  That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fields.General_Information.Well = "name";` should be below. You forgot to instantiate the `General_Information` type and thus it's null. Moreover, not sure what's the need of making them as `partial` class. Shouldn't be actually.

```
fields.General_Information gi = new General_Information();
gi.Well = "name";
```

Comment: Thanks. I just realized it right after I posted the question. They are partial classes because that is how the file is automatically generated.